# Who is the guy in the DotA 2 Trailer?

Tags: dota, dota-2

Here is a link to the trailer: [DotA 2 Trailer](http://www.dota2.com/trailer).

Does this guy have any relevance to the DotA story line or world, or is he just a character they added into the trailer to put a face to the voice?

I am not talking about the heroes, I am talking about the big-nosed fellow who is doing the talking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In all likelyhood, he is the shopkeeper for the store.

DotA has no real plot to speak of.

[image: Leaked picture from dota 2,looks like him and resembles scourge secret shop]

Comment: If you pay attention to what he's saying, this makes perfect sense.  "What does a hero truly need? ... Would you be _X_? ... Then I have _Y_ for you."

Comment: Perfect! I played DotA and i knew there was not much story, thats where the question came from. Way more respect for the shopkeeper now haha.

Answer (score 7):

He is indeed the Shop Keeper of Dota 2 Secret Store.

You can learn more about him by reading [Tales From Secret The Shop - Are We Heroes Yet?](http://www.dota2.com/comics/are_we_heroes_yet/), a comic published by Valve.

[image: Are We Heroes Yet?]
<sub>(source: [steampowered.com](http://media.steampowered.com/apps/dota2/posts/comic_thumbnail.gif))</sub>